# webpack 3 long term caching not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-3

I'm attempting to use webpack v3 to test long term caching. When I build twice by webpack(just make a change to `index.jsx` file), and the hash value changed to `vendor` file.

### webpack.config.js

Reference：[Caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/)

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin')
const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin')
const InlineChunkManifestHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('inline-chunk-manifest-html-webpack-plugin')
// const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')
/**
 * global variable of config
 */
// replace localhost with 0.0.0.0 if you want to access
// your app from wifi or a virtual machine
const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0'
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const allowedHosts = ['192.168.19.61']
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './site')
const distPath = path.join(__dirname, './dist')
const htmlTemplate = './index.template.ejs'
const stats = {
    assets: true,
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    hash: false,
    modules: false,
    publicPath: false,
    timings: true,
    version: false,
    warnings: true,
    colors: {
        green: '\u001b[32m'
    }
}
/**
 * webpack config
 */
module.exports = function (env) {
    const nodeEnv = env && env.production ? 'production' : 'development'
    const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production'
    /**
     * Mete Design Webpack V3.1 Buiding Informations
     */
    console.log('--------------Mete Design Webpack V3.1--------------')
    console.log('enviroment:' + nodeEnv)
    console.log('host:' + host)
    console.log('port:' + port)
    console.log('dist path:' + distPath)
    console.log('platform:' + env.platform)
    console.log('-----------------Mete Design Group------------------')
    /**
     * common plugin
     */
    const plugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            // vendor chunk
            names: ['manifest', 'vendor'] // the name of bundle
        }), // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ //   name: 'manifest', //   minChunks: Infinity // }), // setting production environment will strip out // some of the development code from the app // and libraries
 
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv)
            }
        }), // create css bundle // allChunks set true is for code splitting
 
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name]-[contenthash].css',
            allChunks: true
        }), // create index.html
 
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: htmlTemplate,
            inject: true,
            production: isProd,
            minify: isProd && {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true
            }
        }),
 
    new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin({
            name: 'webpackManifest'
        }),
    new InlineChunkManifestHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            manifestPlugins: [
        new ChunkManifestPlugin({
                    filename: 'manifest.json',
                    manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
                    inlineManifest: false
                })
            ]
        })
    ]
    if (isProd) {
        /**
         * production envrioment plugin
         */
        plugins.push(
        // minify remove some of the dead code
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true,
                conditionals: true,
                unused: true,
                comparisons: true,
                sequences: true,
                dead_code: true,
                evaluate: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true
            },
            mangle: false
        }),
            new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin())
    } else {
        /**
         * development enviroment plugin
         */
        plugins.push(
        // make hot reloading work
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        // show module names instead of numbers in webpack stats
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        // don't spit out any errors in compiled assets
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
        // load DLL files
        // new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({context: __dirname, manifest: require('./dll/react_manifest.json')}),
        // new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({context: __dirname, manifest: require('./dll/react_dom_manifest.json')}),
        // // make DLL assets available for the app to download
        //  new AddAssetHtmlPlugin([
        //   { filepath: require.resolve('./dll/react.dll.js') },
        //   { filepath: require.resolve('./dll/react_dom.dll.js') }
        //  ])
        )
    }
    return {
        devtool: isProd ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-source-map',
        entry: {
            main: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(sourcePath, 'index.js')],
            // static lib
            vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom']
        },
        output: {
            filename: isProd ? 'js/[name]-[hash].bundle.js' : 'js/[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: isProd ? 'js/[id]-[chunkhash].bundle.js' : 'js/[id].bundle.js',
            path: distPath,
            publicPath: './'
        },
        // loader
        module: {
            rules: [
       // js or jsx loader
 
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [['es2015', {
                                        'modules': false
                                    }], 'react', 'stage-0'],
                            cacheDirectory: true // Since babel-plugin-transform-runtime includes a polyfill that includes a custom regenerator runtime and core.js, the following usual shimming method using webpack.ProvidePlugin will not work:
                        }
                    }
        }, // css loader
 
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [{
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    minimize: isProd
                                }
                            }],
                        publicPath: '/'
                    })
        }, // scss loader
 
        /* {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            publicPath: '/',
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [
              // {loader: 'autoprefixer-loader'},
 
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  minimize: isProd
                }
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  includePaths: [sourcePath, path.join(__dirname, './src')]
                }
              }
            ]
          })
        }, */
 
       // images loader
 
                {
                    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8024&name=assets/images/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
 
        },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff2?|otf|eot|ttf)$/i,
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8024&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]',
                    options: {
                        publicPath: distPath
                    }
        },
                {
                    test: /\.md$/,
                    loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), sourcePath],
            alias: {
                md_components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
                md_midware: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/md-midware')
            }
        },
 
        plugins,
 
        stats,
        // webpack dev server
        devServer: {
            // 文件路劲，一般静态文件需要
            contentBase: '/',
            // 是否启用gzip压缩
            compress: true,
            // 是否启用热替换
            hot: true,
            port,
            // 开启任意ip访问
            host,
            // 允许列表中host访问
            allowedHosts,
            // 取消host列表安全检查，开发环境启用，默认关闭，开启则allowedHosts无效
            // disableHostCheck: true,
            // 关闭webpack重启打包信息，错误和警告仍然会显示
            noInfo: true,
            // 浏览器全屏显示编译器错误信息
            overlay: true,
            // 公共文件，浏览器可直接访问，HMR必须
            publicPath: '/'
        }
    }
}
```

### fisrt build

`js/vendor-a674cd02275fdf4760bd.bundle.js     343 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendor`

### second build(just update `index.jsx`)

`js/vendor-f8d5fc2097878041c158.bundle.js     343 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendor`

**Both hashes change even though I only updated the index file.**

### Help

**Anyone can help me to check this problem? Thanks.**

**Github Repo:[webpack_long_term_cache_test](https://github.com/GoDotDotDot/webpack_long_term_cache_test/tree/master)**

Comment: fixed.  [github](https://github.com/GoDotDotDot/webpack_long_term_cache_test/commit/9d02b3e4d29322c5906b8ab7fb90818e70613e17)

Comment: sorry for the downvote. It's a mistake. But i don't know how to change it. It should be an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filename in output use `chunkhash`, and reset the CommonsChunkPlugin name: `['vendor', 'manifest']`

Comment: Who can explain why `manifest` and `vendor` need to be swap order?